# Starting a Springboot application in Eclipse on Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, tomcat9

I am trying to run a springboot application on embedded Tomcat server in Eclipse. The project is added successfully to the server but it never starts.

My application code is below:

```js
import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.boot.Banner;
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:simple-camel.xml")
public class CamelApplication {
    private static final String DEFAULT_XML_ROUTE_CONFIG_FILES = "classpath:/routes/*.xml";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("********************* inside the project ******************");
     SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(CamelApplication.class);
        app.setDefaultProperties(getDefaultProperties());
        app.run(args);
    }
    private static Properties getDefaultProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("camel.springboot.main-run-controller", "true");
        return props;
    }
}
```

My build.gradle is below:

```js
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java'
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.2.6.RELEASE"
}

group 'com.firas'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
apply plugin: "java"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.apache.camel:camel-bom:2.25.0"
    compile "org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.25.0"
    compile "org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot-dependencies:2.25.0"
    compile "org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot-starter:2.25.0"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.4.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.4.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-tx:4.0.4.RELEASE"
    compile "org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-timer-starter:2.25.0"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.2.6.RELEASE"
    
    
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.13'
}
springBoot {
    mainClassName = 'CamelApplication'
}
bootJar {
    mainClassName = 'CamelApplication'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Start-Class': 'CamelApplication'
    }
}
```

and below is a screen shot of my Deployment Assembly configuration:

[image]

Any hints or guidance on how to fix it? I am not seeing any errors in the log so I am flying blind here.

Comment: How are you launching your application? Be specific.

Comment: I right click on the tomcat sever, add the project and then click on the start button in the server tap. This is the way I have been using for other projects.

Comment: Spring Boot doesn't deploy that way. You run `CamelApplication` as a Java application.

Comment: That is not true. You can run Springboot as a Java application since it has an embedded Tomcat instance by default. You can also run it in an application server by removing this embedded instance. I am already able to run it in Tomcat in Intellij so the issue is in Eclipse configuration,

Comment: If you're not seeing errors, what are you seeing? What leads you to conclude that it never starts?

Comment: Tomcat log does not say it started or loaded like it should and nothing runs in my application.

Comment: Can you show the log contents?